# How do I define a pkcs11 attribute for a RSA private key that can store metadata like IV or date of generation used to the key?

Tags: c++, pkcs#11, softhsm

According to the latest PKCS#11 spec the typical attribute structure of a RSA private key is the following:

```
CK_ATTRIBUTE template[] = {
{CKA_CLASS, &class, sizeof(class)},

{CKA_KEY_TYPE, &keyType, sizeof(keyType)},

{CKA_TOKEN, &true, 1},

{CKA_LABEL, label, sizeof(label)},


{CKA_SUBJECT, subject, sizeof(subject)},

{CKA_ID, id, sizeof(id)},

{CKA_SENSITIVE, &true, 1},

{CKA_DECRYPT, &true, 1},

{CKA_SIGN, &true, 1},

{CKA_MODULUS, modulus, sizeof(modulus)},

{CKA_PUBLIC_EXPONENT, publicExponent, sizeof(publicExponent)},

{CKA_PRIVATE_EXPONENT, privateExponent, sizeof(privateExponent)},

{CKA_PRIME_1, prime1, sizeof(prime1)},

{CKA_PRIME_2, prime2, sizeof(prime2)},

{CKA_EXPONENT_1, exponent1, sizeof(exponent1)},

{CKA_EXPONENT_2, exponent2, sizeof(exponent2)},

{CKA_COEFFICIENT, coefficient, sizeof(coefficient)}

};
```

However, there is another attribute `CK_VALUE` that can only be used for creating pkcs 'data objects' and NOT 'key objects'. When I use this field `CK_VALUE` to create key objects PKCS throws me an invalid attribute error. 
I would like to use a similar field in the which contains a string formatted value that can hold metadata information related to the key (like IV used to wrap the RSA key, date of generation of the key, etc). Is there a way to store these information in the existing pkcs11 template without tinkering with the attribute data structure in the implementation? I am using OpenDNSSec community's SoftHSM n2.0 package for the pkcs implementation.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You may use the `Start_Date` attribute of the PrivateKey Object to store the created date. `CK_VALUE` is the attribute that holds the actual value that makes the PrivateKey. You may use `Data Object` that are meant to store any data, to store your metadata like the IV and other info. And you could create a mapping mechanism to the corresponding PrivateKey Object.

Comment: Is it necessary to store this metadata inside the token?